# Putting numbers in a column in parentheses

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to put numbers in some `siunitx` columns in parentheses like this:

```
----------------------------------
         time/s (efficiency/%)    
     -----------------------------
ID    strategy A      strategy B  
----------------------------------
 1   12.34 (12.34)   12.34 (12.34)
 2   12.3   (2.34)   12.3   (2.34)
 3    2.34 (12.3)     2.34 (12.3) 
----------------------------------
```

I found that this can be done with `>` and `<` options, but the last column looks bad:

```
-----------------------------------
         time/s (efficiency/%)     
     ------------------------------
ID    strategy A       strategy B  
-----------------------------------
 1   12.34 (12.34)   12.34 (12.34 )
 2   12.3   (2.34)   12.3   (2.34 )
 3    2.34 (12.3)     2.34 (12.3  )
-----------------------------------
```

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-family=true,
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-mode=true,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true
}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{{(}}S[
  table-format=#1,
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false,
  table-space-text-pre=(,
  table-space-text-post=)]<{{)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{~}
  P{2.2}
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{~}
  P{2.2}
}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{time${}/{}$\si{\s}
    (efficiency${}/{}$\si{\percent})} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ID} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{strategy A} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{strategy B} \\
  \midrule
  1 & 12.34 & 12.34 & 12.34 & 12.34 \\
  2 & 12.3  &  2.34 & 12.3  &  2.34 \\
  3 &  2.34 & 12.3  &  2.34 & 12.3  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpting from section 7.13, "Adding items after the last column of a tabular", of the user guide of the siunitx package:

> When using the array package ‘`<`’ construct to insert material after an `S` or `s` column, the
>   alignment of the final column may be wrong if the standard tabular row terminator `\\`
>   is used. This is due to the way that LATEX constructs tables at a low level. The incorrect
>   spacing can be avoided by using the TEX `\cr` primitive to end the table rows.

In the specific case of your table, it's necessary to use `\cr` only for the three data rows; the two header rows aren't subject to the `<{{)}}` operation and can thus be terminated with `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true
}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{{(}}S[
  table-format=#1,
  table-align-text-pre=false,
  table-align-text-post=false,
  table-space-text-pre=(,
  table-space-text-post=)] <{{)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=2.2] P{2.2}} @{}}
  \toprule
  ID & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{time$/$\si{\s} and
    (efficiency$/$\si{\percent})}   \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-5}
   &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{strategy A} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{strategy B} \\
  \midrule
  1 & 12.34 & 12.34 & 12.34 & 12.34 \cr
  2 & 12.3  &  2.34 & 12.3  &  2.34 \cr
  3 &  2.34 & 12.3  &  2.34 & 12.3  \cr
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```